# How to set value to Input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't set value in input:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycontroller as controlss">

<input type="text" class="form-name  ng-pristine ng-empty ng-valid-vin ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" name="inputUser" ng-model="user.name" ng-required="toReq('user.name', data.assist)" required="required">
```

and trying to use script:

```
var test = angular.module('myApp', []);

test.controller('controlss', ['$scope', function ($scope)
{

$scope.user ={ name: 'MAX'}; 

}]);
```

What am I doing wrong?
 Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

The ng-model input `user.name` has the controller name missing, which is `controlss` in your case:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycontroller as controlss">

<input type="text" class="form-name" name="inputUser" ng-model="controlss.user.name" ng-required="toReq('user.name', data.assist)" required="required">
```

There is a good example for this in the angularjs docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Answer (score 0):

you should fix your code to like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controlss">
<input type="text" class="form-name  ng-pristine ng-empty ng-valid-vin ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" name="inputUser" ng-model="user.name" ng-required="toReq('user.name', data.assist)" required="required">
```